# How to hide connection string of postgresql in DbContext ... EF 6(not core)

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework, .net-6.0

I have a web application. if I use Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore I can hide connection string in appsettings.json file but I want to use EntityFramework6.I followed the instructions at npgsql entityframework documentation. so my first problem is that .net 6 doesnt generate default web.config or app.config file,it only has appsettings.json. In documentation there is info like this;
[image]

so first I added connection string to appsettings.json it didnt worked it gave the same error  I tried to create my own app.config file and copy-paste that configuration provided at documentation made the changes (connection name,npgsql version,public key etc).
here is my dbcontext class
[image]

when I try to enable migrations it gives me this error I
[image]

I think it doesnt recognize the app.config file that I created so my question is how can I hide connection string I dont want to use it on dbcontext class

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can still use your custom app.config file. However, I think you should move all the configs into appsettings.json to make it conventional since you moved to .Net 6.

To get the correct connection string section you can access it using public IConfiguration Configuration { get; } in Startup.cs/Program.cs

Notice that the the connection string name in your config is BlogDbContext, you can change it to dbcontext or input the correct name in services.AddDbContext in Startup.cs/Program.cs